# java selenium can not open page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

java (11) selenium with chrome driver version 116.0.5845.96

i want to open this page : https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebusiness/sailingSchedule/searchByCity

and this is the code to init the driver

```
private void initBrowserSeleniumChrome() {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", CHROMEDRIVER);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.logfile", CHROMEDRIVER_LOG_PATH);

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

driver_chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver_chrome.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver_chrome.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Dimension dmn = new Dimension(1280, 1024);
driver_chrome.manage().window().setSize(dmn);
```

}

`driver_chrome` is the WebDriver : `public static WebDriver driver_chrome;`

`CHROMEDRIVER` is the path to the chrome driver

then i open the page with :

```
driver_chrome.get("https://elines.coscoshipping.com/ebusiness/sailingSchedule/searchByCity");
```

but i get this :

[image]

I tried changing several ChromeOptions ... without success...

Comment: Have you tried a different site to ensure things are running correctly?

Comment: I remember having issues with `Selenium` in `Java`. I had to use `io.github.bonigarcia` and then do `WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup(); WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to disable one of the flags that can identify your browser for resources that you using automation.

```java
options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
```

so, full list of flags would be

```java
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
options.addArguments("--disable-infobars"); // disabling infobars
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); // applicable to windows os only
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); // overcome limited resource problems
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
```

[Reference](https://www.zenrows.com/blog/selenium-avoid-bot-detection#top-measures-to-avoid-bot-detection-with-selenium)

Comment: incredible!.. @Yaroslavm... you are a guru!!! :-))